# How to get form results live, when user types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a name calculator on my website and it calculates the vibrations of each letter, for example:

- `A` is vibration `1`,
- `B` is `2`,
- `C` is `3`,
- etc.

Right now when I type a name in the form, I have to press the calculate button, so the program calculates the sum of all letters and it shows the total vibration.

But I want the form to calculate the vibration of the name on the fly, as you are typing it in the form, and without the need to press the button to calculate to get the total sum of the vibrations at the end.

Comment: There is no need to use ajax for this, there is no need to send the data anywhere, a simple javascript calculator doing calculations when a key is pressed, on the current letters would work. But yes, what have you tried?

Comment: Use javascript with the text onchange event.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use AJAX. Assuming you have some function `calculate()`, you can simply gather all your text inputs and bind an event listener to them, like

```
function calculate() { //code }
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]);
inputs.on('keyup', calculate());
```

With this code, everytime any key is up in any focused text input, the function will run. You can also consider [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keydown) or [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keypress) events instead of [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keyup).

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery's keypress function

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
   //on each keypress in input this function will be executed, calculate your vibration for letters here and append the result in the result field
});
```

[Keypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp)

Comment: I havent try anything, the calculator is already done by somebody else, but you have to press calculate button

Comment: so I have a code on the html site, and then php file attached too... shoud I just paste the code?

Comment: the code that execute on button press should execute on keypress function, now you have mention that calculation has been done by some in a php file you have to make an ajax call and pass the value from input to ajax. You have an input field right? @bobo

Comment: yes I have input field, i have many files on my server, that are or are not connected to the calculator......I have jquery cookie, functions.js, fc.js and then 2 php files and the html file where the form is actually, which one should I paste here?  I searched for function calculate code in the functions.js file, could not find function, only calculate mentioned 4 times

Comment: get the id of the input field replace 'input' in above code with your id, now the code that execute on click, copy it and paste it where I have write a comment @bobo

Comment: ok here is my input field  https://snag.gy/rTaXWF.jpg  should I add the code inside the html page?

Comment: there will be onclick(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
 on calculate button tag, or just search the id of button tag in js file @bobo

Comment: ok here are screenshots  or 4 instances of calculate in my php code  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/emdhue4b2xcmgqb/AACyI0FfmxXlG-UGzZkPuhU2a?dl=0

Comment: these are your function that calculates, now find from where its calling.there will be a click event with your button tag.@bobo

Comment: I searched functions.js again and I found this  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9xno194l78td7p/3.jpg?dl=0   is this it?

Comment: this function does something else, may be formatting or something while you enter search term. but just in this code you have to add your code for calculation, that firing on click event, You have to figure out that, I wont be able to help more.@bobo